# How to define the return type of a method that returns a process object in Powershell

Tags: powershell, oop, process

```
$proc = Start-Process -FilePath '.\ScheduledLogoff.bat' -ArgumentList $ManualAuthTimeout_min -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden
```

The command line above returns a process object for the process that the cmdlet starts.

I need to create a method for `MyClass` that may return the process object, but I do not know how I have to define the return type for my method. How may I define it?

Just to contextualize:
My goal is start a 2nd process then, get the process object for the 2nd process inside a 3rd process through a pipe (xml) that shares an object that has this process object as a property and more other a few properties.

```
class MyClass
{
    Hidden [???]$batProcessObj

    [???]get_batProcessObj()
    {
        $this.batProcessObj = get_from_xml
        return $this.batProcessObj
    }

    [void]send_batProcessObj($value)
    {
        $this.batProcessObj = $value
        update_xml($this)
    }
}
```

## Process 1:

```
$myObj = New-Object MyClass

#Creating process 2:
$proc = Start-Process -FilePath '.\ScheduledLogoff.bat' -ArgumentList $ManualAuthTimeout_min -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden

$myObj.send_batProcessObj($proc)
```

## Process 3:

```
$myObj = New-Object MyClass

$Process2 = $myObj.get_batProcessObj()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I have misunderstood what you require, the result of [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7#outputs) is a `[System.Diagnostics.Process]` when using the `-PassThru` parameter.

> This cmdlet generates a System.Diagnostics.Process object, if you specify the PassThru parameter. Otherwise, this cmdlet does not return any output.

You can check this by running the following command based off your code above.

```bsh
$proc.GetType().FullName
```

Your return type would simply be like so.

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]get_batProcessObj()
{
    $this.batProcessObj = get_from_xml
    return $this.batProcessObj
}
```

Comment: Actually, what worked for me was `System.Object` instead

Comment: You should be careful about using [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=netcore-3.1) because it is the base type for all .NET types. Of course it will work, but it will be a valid result for your method to return any type of object. This could cause errors further on if you intend to use this output for functions or methods that expect a process. Worth noting.